# How to use KIvMob in Kivy displaying ads?

Tags: python, kivy

I am currently trying to put ads on my kivy apposing kivmob.
I red this documentation from kivmob http://kivmob.com/.
I understood everything but I cannot understand what I should add on:

```
self.ads = KivMob()
```

This is my full code. So what should I add on the line where self.ads = KivMob() is

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,NoTransition,CardTransition
from kivy.uix.button import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from functools import partial
import requests
import json
from os import walk
from kivmob import KivMob, TestIds

class MainApp(App):
    # me = 1

    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def on_start(self):
        self.ads = KivMob( ) # so what should I add here
        self.ads.new_banner("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713", top_pos=True)
        self.ads.request_banner()
        self.ads.show_banner()



    def change_screen(self,screen_name):
        # get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        # screen_manager = self.root.ids



MainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also researching on this topic i also want to pubish my app on play store.

From my understanding till now.

you have to change the following:-

```
self.ads = kivmob(YOUR_APP_ID)  /*you are provided with an app id when you sign up on 
                                  google admob. Paste that id here */

self.ads.new_banner("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713", top_pos=True) #This is OK!

self.ads.request_banner()       #add this line for requesting banner ad
self.ads.show_banner()          # Finally Show the banner
```

Use android ndk version 19b in buildozer.spec file to build your app.

Comment: I did the same, and when I run the programm, no ad is showing up. I am using the test banner id.

Comment: Did it work for you. Did you display a add. Could u please say when u did it

Comment: The ads will not show on windows.You must have to package the main.py to apk using buildozer.

Comment: I have done it, but no success. could u please send ur buildozer.spec file

Comment: But i am still struggling on rewarded video ads. How do my app knows that the user watched the full ad or not so that i can fire the rewards accordingly

Comment: And is my code right. Because I am not sure whether I wrote the code correct. Should it be under on_strart or under build. Are u using python2 or python3

Comment: Thank u sir for helping me out.

Comment: I am using python 3.7 i always prefer it to write such things in build function as the ads are loaded first on launching the app in background saves time and app becomes efficient

Comment: could u please show me the buildozer.spec file. I think I have a error there

Comment: Tell me are you using single banner ad unit for all screens or different banner ads for different unit.

Comment: no, sir in my main.py I have one banner unit under on_start(self). And whenever I change the screens, I can see the ad

Comment: Are you using test ads or your own admod id ads on your device.

Comment: Can we connect on whatsapp or anything like social media If you are on instagram dm me @abhaygupta1609.

Comment: @AbhayGupta, can you help me with my question about kivmob? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61950977/kivmob-doesnt-show-ads-in-android-app-python-kivy

Comment: @pinkcat  I added an answer to your Question go check it.

Comment: Yes they only show on mobile phones. If you want to see them on laptop/PC build the apk and use a emulator such as nox player.