# kivmob doesn't show ads in android app python kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy, ads

I try to add ads in my app. I added in my buildozer.spec:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
requirements = python3,kivy, jnius, kivmob
android.api = 28
android.minapi = 21
android.sdk = 24
android.ndk = 19b
android.gradle_dependencies = 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
p4a.branch = master
android.meta_data = com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID=#here id of my app
```

I have code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivmob import KivMob
class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        try:
            fl = FloatLayout()
            self.ads = KivMob('')#here my app
            self.ads.add_test_device(here my id)
            self.ads.new_banner('', top_pos=True)#here my banner
            self.ads.request_banner()
            self.ads.show_banner()
        except Exception as error:
            fl.add_widget(Label(text=str(error), font_size=(30)))
        return fl
    def on_resume(self):
        self.ads.request_banner()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

when I start this app, I see black screen and nothing else. I expected banner. How to fix it? I hope you help me

UPDATE:
if I use `TestIds.APP` and `TestIds.BANNER` it works and shows ad. Why does it happen? How to use real ad banner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So firstly add android in requirements in buildozer.spec.
android.api = 28

Yes using TestIds provide ads to be displayed on any device because they are sample ads by google.

But when you are using your own ad units you create from admob account.
You have to provide your test device id in your code in order to recognise google that you are testing your own ads.

Use self.ads.add_test_device(YOUR_DEVICE_ID) in your build method.

And where did you get your device ID 
Well you have to find your device id in logcat output.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I changed my code, but it didn't help me. What have I done wrong? In my application, all the same, only a black screen. I received my account confirmation email from Google a day ago. Should the app be in PlayMarket to display real ads?

Comment: No it doesn't need to be on play store for showing ads in android.

Comment: I think you used a Device ID app for getting device ID if you do so you are going wrong because the apps are fake.

Comment: You can only get your test device id in logs of your device

Comment: But how does this help to show ads on other devices when the application enters the play market?

Comment: I also don't know how to find out device id without device ID app

Comment: I noticed that ad requests are being sent, but ads does not show

Comment: When you publish your app on the play store google makes the ads global for every device so it doesn't require test device id.     Why google wants test device id ??  Because google want to assure that the developer is not getting paid for clicking ads without publishing to play store. THIS IS ILLEGAL AND UNFAIR for Advertisers.

Comment: Search how to get device logs on google and then after getting logs. Search I/Ads you will get a string of 32 characters its your device ID

Comment: can device id consist of less than 32 characters? I enter: adb shell content query --uri content://settings/secure --where "name=\'android_id\'", and get id, but it is less than 32 characters

Comment: No a device ID cannot be less than 32 CHARACTERS

Comment: Here is the link for tutorial on how to get logs in android.     https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-take-logs-in-android/

Comment: I use logcat[NO ROOT] App in play store for getting logs .

Comment: I hope the last question: where is the device id in the logs? I tried in the logs no root application in search to enter: id, device, device id but could not find.

Comment: after installing logcat app you have to connect it to  computer and give adb permission to devices search and then open your app wait for the app to send ad request . search Ads in logcat and then you will find the Device ID

Comment: I added my test device and now in logs I get error: Ad failed to load : 3

Comment: do not ignore me! please help!

Comment: i told you all the things. now we can do only one thing open your app and note the timings of your app opened and wait for 2 minutes after send me screen shots of logcat application of that particular timeI will give you your device ID

Comment: If the Ad is failed to load don't worry because on a test device ads come after at least 48 hours when you add test device

Comment: I added correct test device id, I waited 48 hours, but I still get error: ad failed to load: 3. what is the reason for this? Did you get this error?

Comment: In the question i saw that the device id is not correct.I told you that the length is of 32 CHARACTERS.

Comment: I added correct id(32 characters), How did I get it? I found it in logs, "Use RequestConfiguration.Builder().setTestDeviceId(Array.asList( here my id 32 characters) to get test ads on this device. After adding id, I get error "ad failed to load: 3" And nothing else.

Comment: Ok then please add logs to the question where did you get ad fails to load.

Comment: Post full logs from starting of the app until closing of app

Comment: Can you suggest what the problem is? I can’t post all the logs, because I don’t know by what keyword or tag to filter the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Kivmob is importing jnius in the process. There for it has to be included in the spec file requirements(you have done it). But you have to use pyjnius instead of jnius
in the requiremnts. This might help you.
But kivmob is also using android module. I don't know how to put that into requirements. So there might be some issues.